# How to store user information

Tags: algorithm, social-networking, facebook-login

I want to know that when we sign up for social networks, how and where does the network store the data and how does it compare the information each time we log in. 
Please answer!

Comment: You are going to have to read a lot about computer security in order to know how login procedure is taking place in a widely use website. Hint: The actual user's password is not stored anywhere in the server.

Answer (score 1):

Most widely used web-sites (that require log-in) use some variation of **[Secure Remote Password Protocol (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol)** in order to authenticate a user.

**Basic answer:**

The passwords themselves are kept nowhere on the server. Instead a *salt* and some number that was generated from the password and salt is kept. This number is actually the "secret password". But the user cannot send it directly, otherwise some attacks (like [man in the middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) can occur, instead - there is a routine including various communication steps that allows the server to authenticate the user and the user to authenticate the server without ever revealing the real password.

**Detailed explanation:**

**On account creation:**

1. The user chooses a password (`pwd`), and a salt (denote `s`) is also
   randomly generated.
2. The user then calculates `H(d,pwd)` - where `H` is a predefined hash
   function.
3. Then `v = g^x mod p` is calculated, where `p` is some prime number.
4. The user sends to the server the values `v` and `s` - and they are
   stored in the password file. The 'secret' in here is the `v`
   password, the salt (`s`) is there to prevent [dictionary attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack)
   on the system if the passwords file was exposed.

**On authentication (login):**

1. The user sends the server the user name.
2. The server replies with the salt
3. The user is then generating using some random number `a` the value: `A=(v^x)^a`, and sends it to the server. (`v` is the number calculated and sent to the server based on the password during account creation).
4. The server is calculating `B=v+g^b` (where `b` is some random number), and sends it to the user along with `u`, which is some random number.
5. The user is then calculating `S=(B-v)^(a+ux), K=H(S), M1=H(A,B,K)`, and sends `M1` to the server.
6. The server then verifies `M1`, and sends the user `M2 = H(A,M1,K)`.
7. The user then verifies the value of `M2`, and effectively ensures he is indeed speaking with `M2`.

During the entire process - the password (or `v`) is never explicitly sent over the web.

---

**The non "secret" data** can be stored in various ways, depending on the nature of the social network and the users' behavior. A common way to do it is using [relational data base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), such as [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).